# Parsing date and running into a 'static reference to the non-static method' Error in java

Tags: java, date-format, non-static

I have a line in my main like so:

```
Date gameDate = DateFormat.parse(scanner.nextLine());
```

Essentially I want to scan in a date with util.Scanner

Which hits the error:

> *Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method parse(String) from the type DateFormat*

Now, I've looked in to this error, but it doesn't seem as clear cut as this [example](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/toptenerrors.html).

How do I get round this?

Comment: `DateFormat.getDateInstance().parse(scanner.nextLine())`. But in all probability you'll need to specify the format.

Comment: Now we can sit back and watch the karma vultures swoop in.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik why do I need getDateInstance?

Comment: Well, you need **some** instance of `DateFormat` or its subclass. I gave you an example that gets you an instance with the least code. Adapt it to your needs. For example, you'll get all you need with a `SimpleDateFormat`. Check out the Javadoc.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, Ah, I beleive my error was in thinking the *Format* in `DateFormat` was a verb, not a noun; I thought it was some sort of method, not a class.

Comment: I am astonished that 2 hours later still nobody (myself included) has raised the issue of using Joda-Time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`parse()` is not a static method. It's an instance method. You need to create a DateFormat instance, and then call `parse()` on this instance:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date gameDate = dateFormat.parse(scanner.nextLine());
```

A static method belongs to a class. It doesn't make sense to call `Person.getName()`. But it makes sense to call

```
Person pureferret = new Person("Pureferret");
String name = pureferret.getName();
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [API Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html):

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
myDate = df.parse(myString);
```

Comment: @Marko an abstract (non-instantiable) class can still have static (class-level) methods

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an instance of DateFormat in order to call "parse".
Only static methods can be called without istantiating an instance of the specified class.
You can get an instance with the default DateFormat calling:

```
DateFormat.getInstance()
```

then you can call

```
DateFormat.getInstance().parse()
```

or you can define your own DateFormat using for example a subclass of DateFormat, as SimpleDateFormat.

```
DateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
myFormat.parse(myString);
```

Check here how you can customize it:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

`DateFormat` is an abstract class that needs a concrete instantiation.

e.g.

```
   DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(...);
```

Check out [this example](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-simpledateformat-class-formating-parsing-date-and-time/142) to see how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd"; // put proper format here
Date gameDate = new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(scanner.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 1):

The method parse of the class DateFormat is not static. You must instantiate a DateFormat object first before you can call it's parse method.

You also must configure the "rules" of your date format so the parser knows what and how to parse.

See SimpleDateFormat class:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html